# Lag Function in pyspark not showing the all the data

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, lag

I have a fact data table which shows sell data (price, units, volume, and so on)
I need to add to the actual dataframe the same columns but with the name "prev_year" at the end of it, showing the previos year values from the same row in the same period and previous year.
something like this:

> ```
> +---------+------+------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+
> |year|period|sales_unit|sales_value|sales_unit_prev_year|sales_value_prev_year|
> +---------+------+------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+
> |     2023|     1|        50|         15|                45|                   14|
> |     2023|     2|        55|         16|                50|                   15|
> |     2022|     1|        45|         14|                 0|                    0|
> |     2022|     2|        50|         15|                 0|                    0|
> |     2021|     1|        40|         13|                 0|                    0|
> ```

I tried this the code below but only display in year column the value 2020 and the period 12 for some reason.

```
    lag_years = 1

    lag_window_spec = Window.partitionBy("period").orderBy("years")


    fact_data_columns = ["sales_unit", "sales_value"]  # they're more columns but only add these 2 for the example
    lagged_columns = []
    for col_name in fact_data_columns:
        lagged_col_name = f"{col_name}_prev_year"
        lagged_columns.append(lag(col(col_name), lag_years).over(lag_window_spec).alias(lagged_col_name))
    

    result = fact_data_df.select("*", *lagged_columns)
    
    
    result.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code

Create a dataframe corresponding to the previous year values from fact data columns by adding the `lag_years` to the `year` column.

```
lag_years = 1
fact_data_cols = ["sales_unit", "sales_value"]

prev = df.withColumn('year', F.col('year') + lag_years)

# prev.show()
# +----+------+----------+-----------+
# |year|period|sales_unit|sales_value|
# +----+------+----------+-----------+
# |2024|     1|        50|         15|
# |2024|     2|        55|         16|
# |2023|     1|        45|         14|
# |2023|     2|        50|         15|
# |2022|     1|        40|         13|
# +----+------+----------+-----------+
```

Rename the fact data columns in the previous year dataframe by adding `_prev_year` suffix

```
prev = prev.select('year', 'period', *[F.col(c).alias(f'{c}_prev_year') for c in fact_data_cols])

# prev.show()
# +----+------+--------------------+---------------------+
# |year|period|sales_unit_prev_year|sales_value_prev_year|
# +----+------+--------------------+---------------------+
# |2024|     1|                  50|                   15|
# |2024|     2|                  55|                   16|
# |2023|     1|                  45|                   14|
# |2023|     2|                  50|                   15|
# |2022|     1|                  40|                   13|
# +----+------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Join the dataframes

```
result = df.join(prev, on=['year', 'period'], how='left')

# result.show()
# +----+------+----------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
# |year|period|sales_unit|sales_value|sales_unit_prev_year|sales_value_prev_year|
# +----+------+----------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
# |2023|     1|        50|         15|                  45|                   14|
# |2023|     2|        55|         16|                  50|                   15|
# |2022|     1|        45|         14|                  40|                   13|
# |2022|     2|        50|         15|                null|                 null|
# |2021|     1|        40|         13|                null|                 null|
# +----+------+----------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
```